# Name for someone whose interest might be to discredit one's results by trying to find hypothetical mistakes?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

**What do you call a person whose interest might be to *discredit* your results by trying to find hypothetical mistakes? This person does not seem to focus on solving a problem with pragmatism. Is there a word or an expression for that?**

I came up with an answer and the described solution seems valid. Most participants give good feedback, except this one particular person.

My feeling is that this person merely wants to discredit my solution/answer. I suspect that he/she does this in order to favor his/her own answer/solution.

P.S.: If possible I'd like to put it in a (*most*?) polite way. Let's say I am talking to the Queen of England and I want to tell that she ...

P.S.S.: Of course I am interested in other (formal, familiar, vulgar, etc.) words or expressions too. But let me know in which context it can be used appropriately.

Comment: Whether they *merely* want to down your solution is essential here. Perhaps they want to down your solution *because they think it's wrong*. In that case, they are not *merely* downing your solution. So, does this refer to a person who has *bad motives*, or to one who is making a particular kind of analytical mistake?

Comment: I assume bad motives, but I am interested also the other expression

Comment: "Mary, Mary quite *contrary,* How does your garden grow?" Is that nursery rhyme still known and chanted? I thought the American equivalent was "just plain cussed."

Comment: @Hugh As a college-age American, I can say that the rhyme isn't entirely unknown, though it's not all that common. I'd agree that "contrary" could be quite applicable.

I've never heard the phrase you mention though, so I don't think it's currently well-known American English.

Comment: @HammerN'Songs good to know. Then, 'plain cussed' must be from celluloid cowboy films.

Comment: @Hugh - the phrase "just plain cussed" is indeed from old Western films, but it actually means annoyed or frustrated. I grew up in Texas and you still hear the phrase from time to time. For example, if I'm building a deck and everything's going wrong, then my wife asks me how the project is going, I could say I'm "just plain cussed." The implication is that I'm ready to start cussing (ie - using profanity).

Comment: In mostly math and science contexts, when someone approaches a question with too much of a preconceived notion of its solution, and therefore might tend to cavil when a novel idea is presented as a response, it's said that he/she has a "solution looking for a problem."

Comment: I have called such a person an "analytic paralytic" by construction from "analysis paralysis", even though such a construction has defects.

Comment: In your case, the best word for the other person is **right**. You freely admit that you have no idea whatsoever whether the bad circumstances exist that cause your proposed solution to fail -- that means that it is *your assumption that they won't exist* that is bad, and his objection is perfectly legitimate under the rules of logic.

Comment: Is there a reason this is cross posted on both ELU and ELL? One of them needs to be removed as cross posting is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Catija I was hoping to find an answer in either. I thought it is good for both networks, also for those who want to learn. I see myself as being quite proficient in the English language; so I usually use the other network. But to be honest, there are English learners here who might benefit from that. I wonder why *cross posting* is strongly discouraged. Is it your opinion or do you base your remark on Q&A guidelines from the networks? By the way, you cross posted your comment in both networks too. Wouldn't that be strongly discouraged?

Comment: Hi dear users, I really do apologize :-( I reworded my question. I was forced into it because the administrators strictly prohibit posting the same question on the other English speaking network for learners. In order to make them not remove it I had to rephrase. I tried to give this question an edge, a slightly higher level of difficulty if you so will. The answer remain good in my opinion, but you might want to edit though. So sorry really. SE, not being able to cope with cross posts, is not tolerant towards identical postings even if there is a benefit for everyone there.

Comment: In your case `scandalmonger` or `busybody` fit in the description

Comment: @jsoteeln To me, "a solution looking for a problem" is a technique that probably seems interesting but has no applications. It has nothing to do with preconceptions.

Comment: *I suspect that he/she does this in order to favor his/her own answer/solution.* It sounds like the person is a competitor or rival. Competition between alternative proposals can be healthy and productive. Or not - it can instead be abusive, unfair, etc. The context is not clear enough, so neither is the question. Unless you clarify it, it should be closed as unclear. You can see that the answers are all over the map, trying to guess whether the person is just negative about everything or out to get you, etc. Quite unclear.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Such an individual could be described as a ***cynic***, or a ***cynical*** and ***captious*** person.

**Caveat**: when expressing such an evaluation to royalty, care must be taken, as unforeseen and quite gruesome consequences can result. First, locate your points of egress. Second, ensure no sharp or blunt objects are within the royal reach, e.g., daggers, scepters, falchions, maces, guillotines, etc. Third, the evaluation should be accompanied with much bowing and scraping.

e.g., "*My Queen, I find your rejection of my suggestions for a wardrobe makeover utterly cynical and captious! Ah, of course I mean that in the nicest, most flattering way, your Majesty*."

> [**cynical**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynical) *adjective*
>
> **1**: **captious**, peevish
>
> **2**: having or showing the attitude or temper of a cynic
>
> [**cynic**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynic) *noun*
>
> **2**: ***a faultfinding captious critic*** (especially: one who believes that human conduct is motivated wholly by self-interest)
>
> [**captious**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captious) *adjective*
>
> **1**: **marked by an often ill-natured inclination to stress faults and raise objections**
>
> **2**: calculated to confuse, entrap, or entangle in argument

(all linked definitions courtesy of Merriam-Webster *online*)

Comment: "Captious" -made my day; +1. Especially after seeing M-W's 'captious sloganeering' and 'captious and cranky eaters.'

Comment: Difficult to make a decision. Many good answers here. Thank you very much Eva (and the others).

Comment: My pleasure Elyasin. You asked a good question that elicited much community response. Good job. :-)

Answer (score 24):

**naysayer**

> nay•say•er   (ˈneɪˌseɪ ər)
>
> n. a person who habitually expresses negative or pessimistic views.
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/naysayer

**Other possibilities**

cynic

defeatist

killjoy

wet blanket etc.

Comment: We can all share here, kids =)

Comment: @LittleEva "cynic" was in this answer [11 minutes before yours](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/259494/1). It was simply reformatted into a vertical list instead of a horizontal one.

Comment: Dear chastely & @Eric, I apologize. I didn't see it before the edit. Thanks for correcting my error, no offense was intended, and the down-vote was not mine.

Comment: I think defeatist is possibly the best answer here, but I still don't think it quite fits

Answer (score 16):

"Nit-picking" is defined by Merriam-Webster as "minute and usually unjustified criticism".  From this comes "nitpicker", someone who engages in nit-picking.

Answer (score 12):

**faultfinder** or **fault-finder** (*noun*):

1. a  person who criticizes someone or something, often in a way that is not fair or reasonable

   Source: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com)
2. a person given to finding fault; chronic captious complainer

   Source: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com)

The first, recorded recipient of the above 'nickname' was most probably [Timaeus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timaeus_(historian)) , the ancient Greek historian.

> *'Timaeus was so free in his criticisms of just about everybody that he was wittily dubbed **Epitimaeus**: Mr Faultfinder.'*
>   Source: [The Greek Historians: Epilogue p101](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=o7aHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=epitimaeus&source=bl&ots=fHg4QvwIg3&sig=irjLSyDEXThWXXmwz0e1zpdGHgE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAjgKahUKEwiyquP2hdzGAhWJthQKHU_1BrA#v=onepage&q=epitimaeus&f=false)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps *[naysayer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer)*

> one who denies, refuses, opposes, or is skeptical or cynical about something

*Merriam-Webster*

Comment: Two users have posted "naysayer" as an answer, this one was posted first. If you like this term then consider giving credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 8):

The obvious ***pessimist*** applies as a derivative of *[pessimism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pessimism)*:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1 A tendency to see the worst aspect of things or believe
>   that the worst will happen:

Answer (score 6):

Your compatriot is a *[crepehanger](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crepehanger)*

> noun
>
> :  one who takes a pessimistic view of things :  killjoy
>
> *man is doomed, say the crepehangers, to overpopulate his planet —Time*

Supposedly from people who compulsively worried about death, which was signified by the *black crepe* hung over windows or worn with the clothing of mourners.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid any overly negative connotation, you can use **playing devil's advocate**.

[oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/devil%27s-advocate):

> A person who expresses a contentious opinion in order to provoke debate or
> test the strength of the opposing arguments:
>
> "the interviewer will need to play devil's advocate to put the other side's case forward"

Comment: That's a decent phrase but usually somebody playing devil's advocate IS interested in reasoning through the problem. They are just choosing to do so by deliberately presenting a case they don't entirely agree with and seeing if they can make it hold water. Thus, while this phrase might answer the question, I don't think this is the best term for this question. ... I guess you could have somebody playing devil's advocate just to annoy somebody.

Comment: Bobby Kennedy, FTW. [He ain't no *Yes Man*](https://books.google.com/books?id=z2YsYi-8DskC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=Bobby+Kennedy+yes+man&source=bl&ots=qtPFWXlFkq&sig=MlZz57J-_Dl17IrsvtbI7kYjeOY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMI2J_l9_vbxgIVjJmACh24CQCJ#v=onepage&q=%22yes%20man%22&f=false) - I disagree with @MarkBalhoff, D.A.'s expect *you* to present a case that holds water, after or while they poke holes in it.

Comment: @Mazura Exactly what I said. I probably should have been clearer with my pronouns that "they can make it hold water" referred to the other people in the group defending the popular stance but I still think that this interpretation of pronouns is the only one that makes sense in the context of the rest of my comment. When the devil's advocator "expect[s] you to present a case that holds water," they are moving toward a resolution which defies the OP's original question premise of "not interested in solving."

Comment: @Mazura FWIW "He ain't no Yes Man" has a similar issue in that it doesn't really indicate the intentions of the person and even then I would expect that phrase to be mostly used more to mean "He's not a suck up" than "He's actively trying to stifle solutions"

Answer (score 6):

Such a person may, more fundamentally, be a *contrarian*.

Answer (score 5):

*[Adversary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/adversary)* describes this person, particularly if their opposition to your solution rises from a preexisting rivalry:

> noun
>
> 1 One’s opponent in a contest, conflict, or dispute:
>
> Origin
>
> Middle English: from Old French *adversarie*, from Latin *adversarius*
>   'opposed, opponent', from *adversus* ... 'against, opposite', past participle of *advertere*, from ad- 'to' + vertere 'to turn'.
>   (see *[adverse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/adverse)*).
>
> *Oxford English Dictionary*

Answer (score 5):

A person who just wants to *down* your solution could very reasonably be called a **Debbie Downer**. From Drita Skilja, [*1001 Idioms to Master Your English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EWizAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&dq=%22debbie+downer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwATgUahUKEwivy9yN5NvGAhXLpYgKHbh9BIg#v=onepage&q=%22debbie%20downer%22&f=false) (2013):

> **A Debbie Downer**—A person who always has something negative to say and brings other people's excitement and happiness down[.] *E.g. Margaret was not invited to the party because she is a Debbie Downer.*

Here's an example of the idiom in use, from Judith Belmont & Lora Shore, [*The Swiss Cheese Theory of Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IGxGkRzjonIC&pg=PA227&dq=%22debbie+downer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAjgeahUKEwj3xIvc5NvGAhWOlYgKHRfUCLs#v=onepage&q=%22debbie%20downer%22&f=false) (2012):

> In counseling, Debbie made a conscious effort to stop focusing on what was wrong. ... Debbie realized that so much of what was holding her back was her **Debbie Downer** attitude. She focused on maintaining a can-do attitude and began to really appreciate all that she had. Debbie's gratitude led to more optimism which allowed her to actually go out and find a fulfilling career.

Likewise from Anthony Davis, [*Men's Book of Knowledge*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fkDd9kmva4wC&pg=PT11&dq=%22debbie+downer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBzgoahUKEwjX28Df5dvGAhWVK4gKHWR5BRQ#v=onepage&q=%22debbie%20downer%22&f=false) (2011):

> [U]se positive language to encourage others and compliment the people around you at every given opportunity. Praise other people's successes; don't be jealous, be happy for them. Motivate and inspire people to succeed beyond their wildest dreams. The “**Debbie downer**” gets nowhere and brings everyone down with him. Don't waste time and energy being discouraged by negative circumstances. There is a positive side in every situation. Find it and the world is yours. Don;'t be the guy who thinks of tasks as impossible. Instead, ask yourself: How can I make this possible? Then take action and do it!

Evidently, the idiom "Debbie Downer" refers to a recurring character who began appearing in *Saturday Night Live* sketches in 2004. But as the third excerpt above indicates, the term may be applied to men or women.

Comment: A "Debbie Downer" is actually someone who presents negativity, without necessarily attempting to discredit or dissuade an argument. Disney's "Eor" character is an excellent example of this. I would not use the phrase when attempting to describe an individual that attempts to present conflict for the purpose of discrediting an opponent during a debate (even if it loosely applied, it lacks an element of intent.) It is also typically used in a negative context, to identify one as Debbie Downer carries a negative connotation, it's tantamount to name-calling.

Comment: I agree with @ShaunWilson. Debbie Downer is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to say that your solution will not present practical difficulties, despite not being perfect theoretically, you can say that the other person is being too ***academic***.

> *Academism results when the reasons for the rule change, but not the rule.* - Igor Stravinsky
>
> *A difference that makes no difference is no difference.* - Beverley Eyre

Answer (score 3):

The chaplain in Joseph Heller's "Catch 22" was

> pinched perspiringly in the epistemological dilemma of the **skeptic**, unable to accept solutions to problems he was unable to dismiss as unsolvable.

[Link on Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=qBlJNb9dhEkC&lpg=PA308&dq=chaplain%20unable%20to%20accept%20solution%20problems%20dismiss%20intitle%3ACatch%20intitle%3A22&hl=de&pg=PA308%23v=snippet&q=Unable%20to%20accept%20solutions%20to%20problems%20he%20was%20unwilling%20to%20dismiss%20as%20unsolvable%20intitle:Catch%20intitle:22&f=false)

But I've got to admit that this doesn't really nail it. The person you're describing is not just a skeptic but also neurotic and stubborn. The word *hypocrite* comes to mind, but doesn't have the component of searching desperately for solutions.

Maybe

**hypercritical hypocrite** ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the person was just giving feedback. Did you ask for the feedback? It's not clear what the relationship is, nor the scenario that prompted the discussion.

I'll go with "constructive feedback"

It's unclear why it's apparently not constructive. Was the feedback wrong? If so, then it's just bad feedback.

If the person has a position of power over you, then it's all different.

I guess the right word depends on the relationship. For instance if a friend or foe.

If the person is simply wrong, then it's just "wrong". 
If it's unclear what's wrong or right, then it's just another point of view.

Comment: I don't know that person. The feedback is unfair because the person is trying to find a mistake in my answer by adding a hypothetical condition of which you simply do not know whether it applies or not. There is no strong reason to make that assumption in my opinion. And thus I have the feeling that this person is merely trying to make my answer look not so good in order that his answer looks good. Neither my answer nor the person's answer are wrong. None of us has a position of power.

Answer (score 2):

### Overcritical

While naysayer is definitely what this person would be, the fact that he/she provides a condition to their argument makes this a critique.

According to your example

> "If **[...]** then it is not OK.

Another example, albeit a cheesy one, is

### A Negative Nancy

or

### Pessimist

Answer (score 2):

Nobody seems to have mentioned

**unproductive**

**unhelpful**

Unproductive seems best in this context as the aim of the meeting is to make a decision, and this person is making no positive contribution towards that goal.

Answer (score 2):

**Pedant** might be a good description of that type of person.

> **Pedant**: *noun*. a person who is excessively concerned with minor details and rules or with displaying academic learning.

- [Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&espv=2&q=define%20pedant)

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, this approach to problem solving can be called *over-engineering*: attempting to design a solution to every possible problem that might arise without regard to their likelihood or importance, when there could be an infinity of such problems.

For example, in software programming, complex problems can have a lot of "edge cases", i.e. uncommon situations a program or its user might experience. Many times a bug in software arises from the programmer's failure to consider these edge cases, so some amount of extra time must be spent finding and addressing them. In many problem spaces, it turns out there can be virtually infinite edge cases, and yet some programmers insist that their product cannot be given to its users until every edge case is addressed. This can lead to similarly infinite delays in the release (and thus delays in revenue generation). If such programmers aren't made to limit their attention to edge cases of a certain significance, then left to their own devices they will certainly *over-engineer* the product, wasting resources and precious time to prevent problems that will likely never occur.

Answer (score 1):

@jsoteeln's comment on the question reminds me that someone who ***cavils*** (makes petty or unnecessary objections) is a ***caviller***

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the term - **Askhole** used to describe this type of person/interaction. This type of person is asking a question not because they are interested in the solution but because they want some kind of interaction.

Comment: There was another recent question where this answer fit, sort of (made up words don't make good answers).  Here, it's not even partially relevant.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. I actually like the answer a lot. Fits better than most other answers plus the pun is funny. +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

It's ***nitpicker*** and not ***naysayer/skeptic***

since you asked about finding fault with hypothetical (or insignificant) details, not just about people who are generally skeptical.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet may be **Hyper-Critical**. Someone that basically will split hairs about everything.

Answer (score 0):

A word which I found today and reminded me of this question is **censorious**.

> **censorious** *adjective*
>
> severely critical of others

*Source: Google*